# What purpose did Lex Luthor's blood have?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In *Batman vs Superman*, Lex Luthor cuts his hand and drops some of his blood on

> Zod to create Doomsday in the spaceship.

Why was his blood necessary/desired for

> the creation of Doomsday? Its not like Lex has any super powers that Doomsday could use. He is highly intelligent, but I am fairly certain that Doomsday didn't benefit from that.

What did the blood do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The movie did not explain that very well, but we can infer what was intended based on the ship's computer's dialogue.

Basically, Doomsday was an "abomination" that was a hybrid of Kryptonian and non-Kryptonian blood. For reasons that are never fully explained, Zod's ship

1. Knew how to create such an abomination,
2. Knew how to use human blood to do it,
3. Had the equipment needed to pull it off,
4. Knew it was forbidden by Kryptonian law (implying that it had been done in the past), and
5. Did it anyway.

It doesn't seem like Luthor's blood *specifically* needed to be used; the implication was that any "foreign" genetic material would have created some kind of similar monster. Luthor, for his part, seemed to expect that using his blood would bind the creature to him and force it to do his bidding. It's not clear from the movie if that actually happened or not, because as soon as Doomsday appears on screen, Luthor basically vanishes until the final scene.

Comment: I think I remember something from the first movie about those scout ships having genetic records and being able to produce life on target worlds, so it's not surprising that it would have all those facilities. Zod's goal in the first one was to use the DNA encoded in Kal-El's to populate the Earth with cloned Kryptonians, so that's clearly something that they do.

Comment: The ability to create life wasn't surprising, based on the fact that Krpyotonians (I believe) were all genetically engineered; the fact that the ship had the facilities to create something illegal, *knowing it was illegal*, and let Luthor do it anyway... that was odd. I have to wonder if there was a scene edited out that explained all that.

Comment: I thought that was pretty clearly explained when Luthor asked where the council was now, and the computer responded that they were destroyed. There's no legal body to enforce the law, so it's no longer relevant.

Comment: @DCShannon: that's a little bit strange that a computer need a legal body to be forced to obey. But that's a very advanced AI afterall...

Comment: yeah, its ability to create kryptonian life wasn't at all surprising... other than the fact that the last movie was all about Zod needing to recover the codex to do it.

Comment: "as soon as Doomsday appears on screen, Luthor basically vanishes" - Lex may be crazy, but he's not stupid.

Comment: Poor Lois there if every non kryptonian hybrid is a monster.

Comment: KutuluMike:: The ship itself was not being held to any specific laws it was merely presenting a statement of fact to Luthor referring to his current act being illegal, allowing him to now become aware of that fact and now, did he in fact wish to continue forward in the face of that knowledge. I mean.. it's all basically implied but I don't believe it to be too far of an implication.. do you?